# Persisted data dissapears when using Homestead

Tags: mysql, laravel, vagrant, homestead, laravel-artisan

There is custom `artisan` command which parses some data and writes it to a MySQL DB. I'm runnng this command manually, so there are no any `schedules` or cron jobs.

After saving the data, I can work with it for some time. Usually it's available from 10 up to 20 minutes. If I reboot my machine after persisting, I can work with data for like an hour. After that table empties by itself, like I `truncate` it.

My custom command has `truncate` command in it's constructor, so parser clears the table and refills it:

```
DB::statement('truncate clauses');
```

But I don't think that's the reason, because cron doesn't run this command or something (even if it would, I'd got table with right data in it).

All other tables are keeping data as usual.

I wonder what causes such strange behavior?

My environment: fresh Laravel 5.2.31, Homestead, Vagrant 1.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `artisan` command constructs all existing commands in the application, regardless of what actual command it executes. If you have your truncate in a constructor, that will run every time the cron hits artisan, or when you do a simple `artisan route:list` or any other artisan command.

To test this, just create a simple command, `exit` in the constructor and run `artisan list`.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation.